# IOC to register repositories in service layer and services in the preentation layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I'm using structuremap to register a service in the controller and i need to register repositories in services too. How I'll do that since they are 2 different projects and need the exact same IOC registration. Actually I'm using It on the presentation layer and injecting services in the controller.
I need to know a good pratice way to make, with the same IOC container, injection in the both projects.

Comment: I find the question unclear: Do you need to register dependencies from several different libraries, or do you need to wire up the same dependencies for two different applications?

Answer (score 5):

Put the IOC container, and any shared service implementations, into a third project (class library) that is referenced by both of the other two.

Comment: That was the obvious answer for me too in the first place, but I just don't knew If it was a good pratice, I need to use the IOC in different projects (UI and services).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to keep a StructureMap registry for each of my projects so they can handle their own configuration. My main project then adds references to each of its dependencies. In my main I usually have a bootstrapper class which is responsible for creating and configuring the container. (I avoid the static ObjectFactory when possible.)

```
    public class ApplicationBootstraper
{
    public IContainer Container { get; set; }

    public ApplicationBootstraper()
    {
        Container = new Container(x=>
        {
            x.AddRegistry<SettingsRegistry>();
            x.AddRegistry<ProjectRegistry>();

            //more registries go here or application specific configuration.
        });
    }
}
```

Regarding having a project take a dependency on another project that is StructureMap aware. Version 2.5.4 added the ability to include another registry in your current registry.

For example I have a "Common" project which I need to take a dependency on I can do the following:

```
    public class ProjectRegistry : Registry
{
    public ProjectRegistry()
    {
        IncludeRegistry<CommonsRegistry>();

        Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.